# How to get photo from stock galleries other than google Photos in Android Lollipop and higher?

Tags: java, android, image

I am using following code to pick an image from gallery.

```
//Override For uploading the image.
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
}

//for showing the selected image.
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode==RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null)
    {
        Uri selectedimage=data.getData();
        imagetoupload.setImageURI(selectedimage);
    }
}
```

It only picks an image from google Photos application. I want to pick images from "Gallery" application which comes as stock gallery in phones. While I choose from my Gallery application image is not picked and while showing the seleected image no image is shown.

Comment: Please do not post questions with screenshots of source code. Please paste in the code as text, as you will see in millions of other questions here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, depending on the version of Android you are running on, as is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Storage).

Comment: I have tried it as well. Still the image is not picked from stock Gallery app.

Comment: @a.sthapit: Edit your question and provide the exact code that you used for `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.

Comment: @a.sthapit: That should be fine. Please note that there is no single "stock Gallery app" in Android. There are hundreds of different "stock Gallery apps" pre-installed on the thousands of Android device models. Perhaps yours does not support `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, though it should. There is little that you can do about that.